# Is it dangerous if I uninstall all the packages in `pip list` on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, pip, permission-denied

The python I use is the one of MacOS. It seems that the python of the system did not carry pip, and pip is installed by myself.

It's very annoying to use the python of the system, there is always the "Permission denied" issue and I'm tired of this. So, I want to uninstall all the packages by pip firstly, and then use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/). Before that, I'd like to know

**Is it dangerous if I uninstall all the packages in `pip list` on MacOS?**

Edit: Currently, there are both Python 2.6 and 2.7 on my mac in the directory: `/Library/Python`. Then can I remove python 2.7 totally and reinstall it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not uninstall MacOS python packages. I did that once. Wasn't a fun time. Even installing new packages can lead to huge problems as dependencies get updated and no longer work with OSX stuff, particularly stuff you can't even update because of SIP.
2. If you make a virtualenv, it will be totally separate from the OSX python. You can use pip in the virtualenv and it will not effect the pip outside of the virtualenv. In otherwords, you don't need to remove anything - just make the virtualenv and start pip insall'ing :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing [Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) from Continuum Analytics and then setting my path to that python. This way I got an updated python to work with (plus a bunch of other advantages) but my Mac could keep Python 2.6 it needs to operate properly.